# SQL SERVER sp_executesql incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-executesql

I have this problem when I am trying to execute sp_ExecuteSql in sql server 2014
there is my stored procedure :

```
alter proc search
@Name nvarchar 
as
declare @SQL nvarchar
declare @Params nvarchar
begin
    set @SQL = N' Select * from Table_1 , Table_2 where (1=1) '

    if @Name is not null
        begin
        set @SQL = @SQL + ' and Table_2.thatoneID = ( Select Table_1.Id from Table_1 where Table_1.Name like ''%''+@Name+''%'' ) '
        end
    set @SQL = @SQL + ' and Table_2.thatoneID = Table_1.Id ; '

    set @Params = '@Name nvarchar'

    execute sp_executesql @SQL , @Params , @Name 
end
```

When I am trying to :

```
Execute search 'hh'
```

I got this Error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29 Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: You should always specify a length of a variable, so `nvarchar(100)` otherwise it will just default to 1 character

Comment: Also, when working with unicode text, use the unicode literals (`N'%'`). Though in this case, you're not going to use any indices anyway :D

Comment: Why dynamic SQL? Why old style joins? Keep your SP simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always specify a length of a variable, so nvarchar(100) otherwise it will just default to 1 character.

Just test what your variables have stored by printing them:

```
print @sql
print @params
```

With no length set, the only thing printed is

```
@
```

Why only "@" and not the "S" from the `SELECT` keyword, for the `@sql` variable? Because you have a whitespace at the start of the `@sql` variable.

As opposed to when setting a size for each variable (I'll just go with max, cause I don't know what length you actually need):

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
    , @Name nvarchar(max)
declare @Params nvarchar(max)
begin
    set @SQL = N' Select * from Table_1 , Table_2 where (1=1) '

    if @Name is not null
        begin
        set @SQL = @SQL + ' and Table_2.thatoneID = ( Select Table_1.Id from Table_1 where Table_1.Name like ''%''+@Name+''%'' ) '
        end
    set @SQL = @SQL + ' and Table_2.thatoneID = Table_1.Id ; '

    set @Params = '@Name nvarchar'

    print @sql
    print @params

end
```

Which will give you:

```
 Select * from Table_1 , Table_2 where (1=1)  and Table_2.thatoneID = Table_1.Id ; 
@Name nvarchar
```

I suggest you try this first and see if you still get the error.

Comment: thanks that fixed my problem but I get another one                                          Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @mohammad.pro Well, then that should imply you create another question. Keep things distinct.

Comment: it's working man thanks ! ^_^ , the 2nd problem was with '=' "subquery" it should be 'in' instead of equal

Answer (score 1):

At first - please use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx).

Second, rewrite your query, you are using [old ANSI style](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/09/30/the-old-inner-join-syntax-vs-the-new-inner-join-syntax/).

Third - define `nvarchar` size.

Forth - why you even use dynamic SQL??

```
ALTER PROC search
    @Name nvarchar(max)
AS

SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 
    ON t2.thatoneID = t1.Id 
WHERE (1=1) AND t1.Name LIKE '%'+@Name+'%'
```

If you insist in using dynamic SQL you can use this:

```
ALTER PROC search
    @Name nvarchar(max)
AS
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @Params nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SQL = N'
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 
    ON t2.thatoneID = t1.Id 
WHERE (1=1) AND t1.Name LIKE ''%''+@Name+''%'''

PRINT @sql
SET @Params = '@Name nvarchar(max)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @Name = @Name
```

Comment: my problem is fixed but about why i am using dynamic Sql because i didn't  find another way to do search with different values ,and the (Example above) is just a test for doing this the real one is this

Comment: its says its too long to put in a comment

Comment: Anyway, consider of simplifying your query, as for now - it is mess.